# Directive for dynamically adding JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to use `ng-repeat` to dynamically add script files to my html file?

I have a directive like below:

```
angular.module("app").directive("scriptLoader", function($compile) {
  return {
    template: "<script ng-repeat='s in files' src={{s}}></script>",
    scope: true
  }
});
```

Meanwhile `files` is a scope variable in my controller:

```
$scope.files = ["test.js", "script.js"];
```

And I get the html rendered as:

```
<script-loader class="ng-scope">
  <script ng-repeat="s in scripts" src="test.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
  <script ng-repeat="s in scripts" src="script.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
</script-loader>
```

But it doesn't work since whenever I try to invoke a method from the loaded files, it just says the method is not defined.

I'm just curious why can't I load script like this. Please help!

Comment: @Satpal included info for the same

Comment: @Satpal no I'm _not_ getting any error in console. Also I'm trying this out in Plunker so not sure how to go with an absolute url :(

Comment: `<script>` isn't treated normally by Angular compiler, this was done on purpose. The thing you're trying to do is terrible, it can load scripts multiple times. Don't use templates for things they weren't intended for. If you need to load scripts programmatically, use plain JS.